C# .NET : is "lock" required around ImmutableList reference copy?
A debate formed about a lock statement in our team - I would appreciate some external feedback about this.
The code part in question is:
lock (IndexLock)
{
    currentIndex = Index;
}

You can see part of the class below:
public class BuilderService
{
    private ImmutableList<Model> Index { get; set; } = ImmutableList<Model>.Empty;
    private object IndexLock { get; } = new();

    public Add(Model item)
    {
        lock (IndexLock)
        {
           Index = Index.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Model> GetFilterLinesExcluding()
    {
        var filters = new List<Model>();
        ImmutableList<FilterModel> currentIndex;
    
        lock (IndexLock)
        {
            currentIndex = Index;
        }
    
        foreach (var filter in currentIndex)
        {
            ...
        }        
    }
}

Without going into the details, the debate is around phenomenons like:

memory visibility
memory barriers
stale values

Does it make sense to have a lock around currentIndex = Index?
Threads:

GetFilterLinesExcluding method accessed by multiple threads.
Add method can be called at any time.

I will provide more information if required.
Thank you in advance!

That code smells. Normally you would create another list from an ImmutableList, and not assign it to itself. Do you have an XY problem ?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain ImmutableList.Add() doesn't modify the list, it returns a "new" list with the item added to it. (The underlying code doesn't need to actually make a copy of the list to do that - it's more clever - and efficient - than that!)

@MatthewWatson Index.Add is not atomic, so I guess it makes sense from that perspecitve. However we have no clue about if the list even is modified concurrently by different threads.

Without seeing more of the code I cannot answer the question.  It would depend on what is happening with the treads.  The code will prevent the index ordering from executing out of order like currentIndex = 7 and then 6, instead of 6 then 7.  The code uses very little memory and just will allow only one thread to complete the lock before another thread can go through the lock.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain True, two threads could both call Index.Add() simultaneously and then one of the adds could go missing. However it doesn't make any sense to have a lock around currentIndex = Index; - It would be better to put Thread.MemoryBarrier(); before and after the assignment.

You also might consider using Thread-safe collections.

Thank you for the quick response. I have updated the description by adding questions about how the methods are accessed.  Let me know if you need more. The question is about the need for the lock.


Does it make sense to have a lock around currentIndex = Index?

Yes. Using the lock statement is the easiest way to enforce thread-safety, without having to do a lot of studying. The lock ensures that only one thread at a time can interact with the shared state, making multithreading relatively easy, provided that you are careful and disciplined. The lock statement also adds implicitly the appropriate memory barriers when the execution flow enters and exits the protected section, so you don't have to think about them. Your code in its current state is safe, correct, and reasonably efficient. It makes sense to keep your code as is.

A debate formed about a lock statement in our team.

I guess that someone in your team suggested to remove the lock around the currentIndex = Index; line. Their suggestion is wrong. Their argument most likely is that the ImmutableList<T> is immutable, so it's not possible for another thread to mutate it while the ImmutableList<T> is enumerated. It's a rational argument, but lock-free multithreading is anything but rational. You might not be aware that the C# compiler, as well as the .NET Jitter and the CPU processor, are all allowed to reorder the instructions of a program, providing that the reordering does not affect the execution on a single thread. In other words the compiler/Jitter/processor assumes that your program is single-threaded, unless you tell it otherwise by adding memory barriers implicitly or explicitly. So if you omit the lock around the currentIndex = Index;, instructions that succeed this line might be executed before this line. In this particular case I cannot see anything after this line that can be moved and placed before the line, and cause problems.
There is another source of danger though. The same reordering of instructions that can happen around the currentIndex = Index;, can also happen inside the Add method around the Index = Index.Add(item); line. Instructions related to the Index.Add can be moved and placed after the Index assignment. In other words the Index might be pointing, for a brief period of time, to a partially initialized ImmutableList<T> instance. This window of danger closes when the thread that executes the Index = Index.Add(item); exits the lock block, because there is an implicit memory barrier placed there. So by omitting the lock around the currentIndex = Index;, you are risking that some threads will try to enumerate ImmutableList<T> instances that are partially initialized, resulting in undefined behavior. The lock around the currentIndex = Index; prevents this, by ensuring that this window of danger will never be open. No thread will be able to enumerate a ImmutableList<T> instance before the memory barrier in the Add has been issued.
As a side note, an alternative to locking that might be suitable for your scenario, and is also non-contentious and more efficient, is the volatile keyword:
private volatile ImmutableList<Model> _index;

// Not thread-safe. Only one thread is supposed to call it.
public Add(Model item)
{
   _index = _index.Add(item);
}

// Thread-safe. Multiple threads can call it.
public IEnumerable<Model> GetFilterLinesExcluding()
{
    List<Model> filters = new();

    foreach (var filter in _index)
    {
        ...
    }        
}

The volatile adds the appropriate barriers whenever the _index is read or written, preventing the scenario of an ImmutableList<Model> being viewed in a partially initialized state.
In case you wanted to make the Add thread-safe as well, without using the lock statement, you could use the ImmutableInterlocked.Update API. This would prevent race conditions that could cause some Model items to be lost.
Although this use of the volatile is safe and correct, you might still prefer to avoid it because as a keyword is rather mystified. If you see that your coworkers aren't comfortable with it, it might be preferable to stick with the lock, instead of spending time to educate them about the correct use of this advanced keyword.

ImmutableList is thread safe, reference assignment is atomic, I think using lock here doesn't make sense.

"I guess ...", yes, it's about atomicity. The reading of the pointer value, which points to either old or a new collection is safe, but ensuring writing/reading pointer is atomic require lock. From my desktop applications experience atomicity is really not an issue, I read/write values from different threads without locks and never had a problem.

@shingo, any reference to "reference assignment is atomic"? =D

@shingo have you considered all possible instruction-reordering scenarios? Also are you advising to remove the lock around the Index = Index.Add(item); as well?

@Sinatr https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#96-atomicity-of-variable-references

@shingo, thanks, I am quite sure I knew this, but forgot, why would I be so lazy with locks otherwise and having no issues?

@TheodorZoulias No, just the second method. In this question I didn't see such a instruction-reordering scenario. Moreover I'm not sure if it's right or not, but as far as I know, lock is not fast, to prevent instruction-reordering, using Volatile or MemoryBarrier would be better.

'currentIndex' is accessed right after the lock in the foreach. Doesn't that make reordering impossible?

@DavidMolnar yes. No instruction placed after the lock's final } can be moved before the }, because there is an implicit memory barrier there.

@shingo acquiring and releasing an uncontested lock takes around 40 nsec in my PC (I have a slow PC), so I can do it around 25,000,000 times per second. It's quite fast. As for removing the lock around Index = Index.Add(item), it is dangerous for reasons that I have covered in my answer. They are the same reasons that the double-checked locking pattern is dangerous. See for example this answer by Peter Wishart.

Let me split the original question into two more nuanced ones: 1; does it make sense to have a lock around 'currentIndex = Index'? 2; Is the lock required in this concrete code example?

@DavidMolnar I updated my answer. Regarding to idea of omitting the lock around the currentIndex = Index;, I changing my assessment from "possibly harmless" to "definitely dangerous". Also I added emphasis to key points in the answer.

@TheodorZoulias so acquiring a contested lock is slow, and meaningless locks will increase this probability.  I'm just talking about the lock around currentIndex = Index, I've realized the lock around Index.Add makes sense, so my last comment has been changed. currentIndex = Index is a single atomic statement, what kind of unexpected results do you think would occur after removing the lock? The foreach might be run before the assignment? It's horrible if this really happens.

You can check this article, he said: "C# and the runtime are very careful to ensure that such optimizations don’t break ordinary single-threaded code". I think you seem to be overconcerned about the partially initiallized issue. Peter Wishart was unable to demonstrate it. In this answer, the author said this is possible, but he also doubted you would ever run into this mostly. I believe the compiler and runtime can handle this well, otherwise you should see memory barriers everywhere in .NET code.

@shingo it's all explained inside the answer.  Omitting the lock around the currentIndex = Index, opens a small window of time where the enumerating thread might see an ImmutableList<T> instance that is mutating from a partially initialized state to its final immutable state.

@shingo I don't think that I could reproduce this behavior experimentally either. Honestly I haven't tried. It requires a weak CPU architecture, which I don't have, and a compiler that does every reordering that is permitted to do. Whether you want to take the risk is up to you. Personally I don't. The .NET code is indeed fully annotated with volatile fields, in almost all classed that are intended for concurrent use. You can see it in the Task, in the CancellationTokenSource, in the ConcurrentQueue<T>, in the ConcurrentDictionary<K,V> etc. Memory barriers are everywhere.

@shingo "C# and the runtime are very careful to ensure that such optimizations don’t break ordinary single-threaded code" -- Of course. But we are talking about multithreaded code here. Whenever you are doing multithreading using non-thread-safe .NET classes, you are supposed to synchronize the access to the mutable shared state using the lock statement, or some other synchronization primitive. Otherwise your program has undefined behavior. And it will be your fault, not Microsoft's fault. Microsoft dismisses all bug reports about bugs that emerge from incorrect use of their products.

And these comments pretty much close the case.  With lock the code is obviously correct.  Without lock it may well be correct, but it's not obviously correct.
